# jquery pageslide reloads every time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using a jquery pageslide plugin in my page. When the button is clicked to trigger the pageslide, it loads an iframe into the page. When I close the pageslide, it hides the iframe using `display:none`. when the button is clicked again to trigger pageslide, it reloads the iframe again instead of just showing (unhiding) it.

Question: Is there a way to load the pageslide only once prevent it to reload every time?
My Jquery to fire pageslide:

`$('a.open').pageslide({ 'modal': true });`

html:

`<a class="open" href="test.html">CLICK HERE</a>`

Comment: A http://jsfiddle.net/ would be helpful

Comment: not sure how to add plugins in jsfiddle.

Comment: Click "External Resources" on the left menu, or load them manually by dynamically creating a script tag if you are feeling adventures

Comment: how do i reference my local file. I can't find an external link to pageslide plugin

Comment: Well obviously you can't upload a local project. But if it's just a few files you could host them trough http://pastebin.com or https://gist.github.com/ and then include as external resource. If you can't make it work then try putting some more relevant code in your question.